# How to change Google Play Store country on Android Emulator (AVD)?

Tags: android, google-play, emulation, android-virtual-device

I have to download the prod app I'm working on which is only distributed in another country, but cannot seem to do it.

I follow this path: Open Play Store -> Press Profile Icon -> Settings -> General -> Account and device preferences.

Here I only see these 2 subtexts saying "Country and profiles" and "Switch to the  Play Store", but there are no actions to perform.

So how do you change the country?